# Is a change in delta-delta-G typically notated as delta-delta-delta-G?

Tags: thermodynamics, free-energy, notation

I'm currently writing a research paper, and need to refer to a difference between $\Delta{\Delta}G$s. The naive way to notate this would be $\Delta{\Delta}{\Delta}G$, but that looks cumbersome and silly to me for some reason, and I can't recall ever seeing that written down anywhere before. Is that a reasonable/conventional way to notate this? Or is a difference between $\Delta{\Delta}G$s still considered a $\Delta{\Delta}G$ (albeit with some different subscript or something)?

Comment: In crystallography having many stacking operators (e.g. ΔΔΔΔΔΔ∇∇Δ) in a row is a norm.

Comment: It probably isn't too necessary unless you go past three, but you could introduce a notation like $\Delta^{(3)}G=\Delta \Delta \Delta G$

Comment: What physical meaning do you associate with the change in delta-delta-G?

Comment: I shouldn't have used the word change - it's a difference. I'm trying to compare two delta-delta-Gs associated with the same process in two similar systems. I'm trying to assess how similar the behavior is, and this is one of my metrics.

Comment: Maybe you could write like $\partial (\Delta G)$